# EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode equivalent for .NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Is there any equivalent for the `EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode` in .NET Core?
When I build my linq, I want the entity framework to consider the string parameter to be the normal string, and not as unicode (i.e. N'something'). Because prefixing with `N'` causes performance issue.

Comment: Can you add a repro to your question?  This is supposed to work for normal LINQ queries against columns configured in EF as `varchar`.

Comment: I ended adding the following code in my modelBuilder
`modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property<string>("MyColumn").IsUnicode(false);` so that it does not add with `N'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended adding the following code in my modelBuilder

`modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property<string>("MyColumn").IsUnicode(false);`

so that it does not add with N'.